# Can I export game from blender to unreal?

Tags: game-engine, blend-files, unreal-engine

Can I export my game made in blender from blender to unreal without any change?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/

Comment: No, you can not

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that, no

You can Export the Scenes as FBX and import them, though. No game logic will be transfered.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!